# How should I repent for peeking into a family home knowing it was haram?

Tags: tawba, kufr

I peeked in on a family's home through their blinds and had the intention that I was doing this because it was haram, and was kinda mocking it.

I hate what I did and don't really know what I was thinking.
I did this for almost a second upon realizing it was kufr (mocking Islam and doing it because it was haram) I stopped and regretted what I did.

One of the conditions of repentance of a sin being accepted is returning rights would I have to ask their forgiveness to become Muslim again?

Or can I repent for the kufr intention I did only without repenting for peeking in to become Muslim again?